# Requisição Ajax com JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Bom dia,

No meu trabalho foi implantado um sistema de leitor biométrico para controle de saída e entrada de pessoal. Tal sistema dispõe de uma API, que dá acesso aos seus dados. Toda API está em Ajax com JQuery. Eu olhei no W3Schools no site https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp e aprendi como se faz isso. Este é o código da API:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/login.fcgi",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        login: 'admin',
        password: 'admin'
    }),
    success: function(data) {
        session = data.session;
    }
});
```

Sendo assim, fiz o seguinte HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://10.3.48.199/login.fcgi",
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            login: 'admin',
                            password: 'admin'
                        }),
                        success: function(data) {
                            session = data.session;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Teste</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Entretanto, quando clico no botão, ele, no console, me dá erros de `CORS`. Pesquisei no internet e acrescentei a seguinte linha abaixo da linha da url: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *,"`. Isso retirou o erro de `CORS`. Mas, não consigo acessar o servidor. Não aparece erro algum. Também não aparece mensagem alguma. Já tentei dar um `alert` pra ver se aparecia a sessão, mas também nada. Alguém pode me ajudar? Talvez seja erro de semântica do código.

Comment: O que retorna na variável `data`, dentro de `success`? Coloque um `console.log(data)` e veja o que retorna no Console do navegador.

Comment: A API não possui um sistema próprio de autenticação ou já é a que está utilizando?

Comment: use o chrome dev tools e olhe a aba "network" para ver como que a requisição está se comportando.

Comment: Experimenta remover o contentType.

Comment: Usei o console.log(data) e não aparece nada no navegador Firefox e não aparece nada.

Comment: A API possui um sistema próprio de autenticação, mas estou acessando o manual do API do fabricante pra criar nosso próprio sistema de controle de entrada e saída de pessoal, pegando apenas o banco de dados do leitor biométrico.

Comment: Removi o content type mas não vi nenhuma diferença.

Comment: infelizmente aqui na empresa não é permitido usar o Chrome :(

Comment: Estou em dúvida se esse <pre>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *,</pre> está certo.

Comment: Se eu acesso o link http://10.3.48.199/login.fcgi , ele me gera o seguinte no navegador: `{"error":"Invalid data","code":1}`

Comment: Testei tbm o `console.log(...)` no firefox e não funcionou.

Comment: @LuizdaMata, coloca seus contatos no perfil do Stackoverflow. Queria falar contigo.